# Trouble of Handle Control Event in Class C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have made a class that contain such as form,button, etc in **class**. then i create the handle events of them in class. Take a look at my class code below:

```
        public static class InputBox
    {
        static Form form = new Form();
        static Label label = new Label();
        static TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        static Button buttonOk = new Button();
        static Button buttonCancel = new Button();
        public static DialogResult Show(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
        {
            form.Text = title;
            label.Text = promptText;
            textBox.Text = value;

            buttonOk.Text = "OK";
            buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

            label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
            textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
            buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
            buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

            label.AutoSize = true;
            textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

            form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
            form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });

            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            buttonOk.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOk_Click); //this is the handle code
            buttonCancel.Click += new EventHandler(buttonCancel_Click);//this is the handle code

            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;
            form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
            form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

            DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
            value = textBox.Text;
            return dialogResult;
        }

        static void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form.Close();
        }

        static void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("If u click this, You Will Get many Messages as many as you call the class"); 
    }
    }
```

then, i call it  like this in my own form code:

```
string strbuffer; // Global Variable

        InputBox.Show("Hi..?", "What Is Your Name?",ref strbuffer);
            //do something...
            InputBox.Show("Hi..?", "What Is Your Age?",ref strbuffer);
            //do something
            InputBox.Show("Hi..?", "How Many Cars do you have?",ref strbuffer);
            //do something
```

if i call the Class as many as i call it, the old handler will never get dispose so the code in handler control will be excuted as many as you call the class

**i guess the variable doesn't get dispose when the class is unused anymore so the variable always accumulate every times you call it**

**What would be the best way to solve this case?**

Comment: Firstly, can I ask why you are making everything static? If it must be static, move the variables into the show method, so that they do get created each time

Comment: All the form setup work (Or at least the event handler assignments) should be moved to the ctor.  Frankly this entire thing is bizarre though. There is a form designer for a reason, use it.

Comment: if we define static class, Aren't we have to define everything static? the static class, could be called in another class as well.

Comment: Static methods are ok, but static variables are a very bad idea. They are shared references to a single instance, so lead to many issues. The objects can be in an inconsistent state, or two threads could access at the same time, so you dont get expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but if its event related problem I would suggest deallocating the event.

```
static void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        form.Close();
    buttonOk.Click -= new EventHandler(buttonOk_Click); 
        buttonCancel.Click -= new EventHandler(buttonCancel_Click);
}

static void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("If u click this, You Will Get many Messages as many as you call the class"); 
    buttonOk.Click -= new EventHandler(buttonOk_Click); 
    buttonCancel.Click -= new EventHandler(buttonCancel_Click);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've moved the static variables for form, label, textbox etc into the Show method.
This means you get a new instance of these each time you call this method. Hence the Event is not already attached to it.

The event handler then had to change to not reference the static form (that doesn't exist anymore) so we got the reference to the form instance from the button.

```
public static class InputBox
        {

    public static DialogResult Show(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        Label label = new Label();
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        Button buttonOk = new Button();
        Button buttonCancel = new Button();

        form.Text = title;
        label.Text = promptText;
        textBox.Text = value;

        buttonOk.Text = "OK";
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

        label.AutoSize = true;
        textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
        form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });

        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        buttonOk.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOk_Click); //this is the handle code
        buttonCancel.Click += new EventHandler(buttonCancel_Click);//this is the handle code

        form.MinimizeBox = false;
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
        form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

        DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
        value = textBox.Text;
        return dialogResult;
    }

    static void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).FindForm().Close();
    }

    static void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("If u click this, You Will Get many Messages as many as you call the class"); 
}
}
```

Comment: The control variables you defined are not global variable so we can't access them at different void

Comment: agreed, but running another inputbox.show accesses the same variable, if you have multiple inputbox.show in parallel (sounds silly, but think about if these were file downloads instead of input boxes) it will cause issues. So, Its a habit its better not getting into!

Comment: i think deallocating these variable when the class wasn't used anymore is better way. because anything the reasons, we still can't access them in another void.

Comment: Ok, from a purely conceptual model, consider it this way: An input box that you show now is a single instance of the input box. you're unlikely to need the same input box with the same details again. (if you do need to use it again then the input box shouldn't be static at all.) Given you wont need to use it again, then why keep the instance around for the lifetime of the application?

Comment: Also, could you give me an example of something you want to do with the inputbox that would be in another function, that would need acces to the variables?